# Resizing an image using Javascript running in Opera Browser

Tags: javascript, browser, width, opera, viewport

I hope someone can help with this quirky issue I am having with the Opera Browser, I have version 11 Beta installed, but I suspect is a common problem in Opera.

The website and page in question is http://www.amigaos.net/index.html.

At the bottom of the body of the html I have the following code which resizes the 3 images you see on this webpage depending on width of the viewport at page load.  In Safari and FireFox the code works fine, but in Opera the following lines which involve resizing the width and height of an image do not work:

```
document.getElementById('img1').width = '475';
document.getElementById('img1').height = '375';
```

Here is the code in full (sorry, about the layout, stackoverflow hasn't formatted carriage returns correctly)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function GetWidth()
 {
   var x = 0;
   if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
   {
     x = window.innerWidth;
   }
   else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
   {
     x = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
   }
   else if (document.body)
   {
     x = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
   }
   return x;
 }

 width = GetWidth();

 if (width>=1680)
 {
  document.getElementById('img1').width = '475';
  document.getElementById('img1').height = '375';
  document.getElementById('img2').width = '475';
  document.getElementById('img2').height = '375';
  document.getElementById('img3').width = '475';
  document.getElementById('img3').height = '375';
 }
 else if ((width>800) && (width<=1280))
 {
  document.getElementById('img1').width = '300';
  document.getElementById('img1').height = '235';
  document.getElementById('img2').width = '300';
  document.getElementById('img2').height = '235';
  document.getElementById('img3').width = '300';
  document.getElementById('img3').height = '235';
 }
 else if (width<=800)
 {
  document.getElementById('img1').width = '225';
  document.getElementById('img1').height = '195';
  document.getElementById('img2').width = '225';
  document.getElementById('img2').height = '195';
  document.getElementById('img3').width = '225';
  document.getElementById('img3').height = '195';
 }
</script>
```

Comment: fyi: See the button on the text editor that has a bunch of 1s and 0s on it?  Hilight your code and press that to format it properly.

Comment: It also doesn't function when resizing my browser window.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing width and height attributes, I think you can just set width: 33% via CSS and have the scaling happen automatically, regardless of the browser window size.  Better solution than trying to use javascript, IMHO.

Here's a simple tutorial: http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/CSS-Proportional-Image-Scale

Answer (score 0):

you are making this way too complicated.  I don't think your issue is browser-specific, you just need to recode your script.

First.  I would recommmend using percentages.. Not sure how you will guess the visitors browser width in pixels.

Let's say that your three resizeable images are 20% width of your browser.  So your css would be:

```
#img1, #img2, #img3 {
  width: 20%;
}
```

now that your css says that your images are 20% of the total with, you're good to add some js.  Keep in mind that the percentage will be that of its outer container.

```
<script type=text/javascript">
  function resizeImages() {
     document.getElementById('img1').style.height = (document.body.clientHeight - 100) * 0.2;
     document.getElementById('img2').style.height = (document.body.clientHeight - 100) * 0.2;
     document.getElementById('img3').style.height = (document.body.clientHeight - 100) * 0.2;
  }
</script>
```

and most importantly.. call your function:

add this to your body tag:

```
<body onresize="resizeImages()">
```

boom.. you're done.

Comment: (note: the onresize attribute can be added to any div.. allthough I never tested any of this)