# Resizing Images In a Table Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, resolution, image-resizing

I apologize beforehand if none of this makes sense, or if I sound incompetent... I've been making webpages for a while, but don't know any JavaScript.

I am trying to make a webpage for a friend, and he requested if I could write some code to resize the images in the page based on the user's screen resolution. I did some research on this question, and it's kind of similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329269/resizing-an-image-using-javascript-running-in-opera-browser), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097494/resizing-page-elements-based-on-window-size), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838137/jquery-change-height-based-on-browser-size-resize). Unfortunately, those articles didn't answer my question entirely because none of the methods described worked.

Right now, I have a three-column webpage with 10 images in a table in the left sidebar, and when I use percentages for their sizes, they don't resize right between monitors. As such, I'm trying to write a JavaScript function that changes their sizes after detecting the screen resolution.

The code is stripped from my post if I put it all, so I'll just say that each image links to a website and uses a separate image to change color when you hover over it. Would I have to address both images to change their sizes correctly? I use a JavaScript function to switch between them.

Anyway, I tried both methods in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329269/resizing-an-image-using-javascript-running-in-opera-browser) and neither worked for me. If it helps, I'm using Google Chrome, but I'm trying to make this page as cross-browser as possible.

Here's the code I have so far in my JavaScript function:

```
function resizeImages() {
    var w = window.width;
    var h = window.height;
    var yuk = document.getElementById('yuk').style;
    var wb = document.getElementById('wb').style;
    var tf = document.getElementById('tf').style;
    var lh = document.getElementById('lh').style;
    var ko = document.getElementById('ko').style;
    var gz = document.getElementById('gz').style;
    var fb = document.getElementById('fb').style;
    var eg = document.getElementById('eg').style;
    var dl = document.getElementById('dl').style;
    var da = document.getElementById('da').style;

    if (w = "800" && h = "600") {
    }
    else if (w = "1024" && h = "768") {
    }
    else if (w = "1152" && h = "864") {
    }
    else if (w = "1280" && h = "720") {
    }
    else if (w = "1280" && h = "768") {
    }
    else if (w = "1280" && h = "800") {
    }
    else if (w = "1280" && h = "960") {
    }
    else if (w = "1280" && h = "1024") {
    }
}
```

Yeah, I don't have much in it because I don't know if I'm doing it right yet. Is this a way I can detect the "width" and "height" properties of a window? The "yuk", "wb", etcetera are the images I'm trying to change the size of.

**To sum it up:**

I want to resize images based on screen resolution using JavaScript, but my research attempts have been... futile.

I'm sorry if that was long-winded, but thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
init();

function init()
{
    var images = document.getElementById("images");
    for(var i=0;i<images.childNodes.length;i++)
    {
        //scare off possible text nodes
        if(images.childNodes[i].tagName == "IMG")
        {
            images.childNodes[i].width = window.innerWidth * .25;
            images.childNodes[i].height = window.innerHeight * .25;
        }
    } 
}
```

I'm grabbing all of the children from a div with an id of `images` and looping through them whilst excluding all text nodes. Then, all I'm doing is setting the width and height based on the browser width/height multiplied by `.25`.

http://jsfiddle.net/CQsPk/1/

Comment: Will this initialize by itself or should I call it onLoad?

Comment: The code I posted will initialize itself so long as you put it inside a `<script type="text/javascript">` tag.

Comment: Do I need MooTools or jQuery, something for this?

Comment: Okay! I'm just having trouble... nothing wants to work for this problem. Ha, I feel very incompetent! And I'm sorry to trouble you!  Maybe it's because my left div isn't measured in percentage, but pixels.

Comment: Put all of your images inside a div that has an id of `images`, so `<div id="images">`. My code should work just fine then.

Comment: That's what I've done, I've got your code at the top, in the head tag, and a div named "images" inside my left column div. I even moved "images" out of the container and it still didn't work. This is a locally-stored webpage, could it have anything to do with that?

Comment: It worked perfectly fine with the example from the website. I'm going to assume it's just my code. Thanks for the help, I'll see if I can fix it!

Comment: Being situated locally shouldn't be the problem. Try adding the code right before `</body>` and see if that makes a difference. It should.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you very much, I couldn't have done it without your answer! I just need to fix the sizes and I'm ready to go!

Comment: No problem. Be sure to put all of your Javascript in the future right above the `</body>` tag unless a situation calls for otherwise. It reduces the strain for browsers upon loading the page.